# Can't compile ocaml program, "Deprecated syntax, the grammar module is expected"

Tags: ocaml

Trying to compile one program, got

```
Parse error: Deprecated syntax, the grammar module is
```

on the first `expr`

```
open Pcaml
EXTEND
  expr: LEVEL "expr1"
    [[ v = expr; "matches"; p = patt -> <:expr< match $v$ with [ $p$ -> True | _ -> False ] >> ]];
END
```

How to edit this to make it work?

Comment: 1. Can you please add how do you compile it? 2. Can you add `GLOBAL: expr` after EXTEND? I think camlp4 or camlp5 syntax  has been changed....

Comment: Also you can start your journey from camlp4 test files: https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4/blob/trunk/camlp4/test/fixtures/gram-tree.ml for example